# SQL Incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I keep getting this error

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword from*

when I try to run this query. I'm fairly new to SQL so I probably missed something. I'm using SQL Server 2008

Basically what I want to do is for the column `lastreturndate` to have the value
 `= Checkoutdate + Loanperiod`. Since `loanperiod` is in a different table I created a view that contains `Checkoutdate, lastreturndate, loanperiod`.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
Checkoutdate    loanperiod      lastreturndate

  2012-1-01          3           2012-4-01
```

SQL code:

```
DECLARE @lastreturndate DATETIME
SET @lastreturndate = dateadd(month,loanperiod,CheckOutDate)
INSERT INTO Loan(lastreturndate) VALUES (@lastreturndate) 
FROM dbo.returndateview
```

`dbo.returndateview` = is the view I created

Imagelink http://imageshack.us/a/img69/3048/68810818.png to the ERD

Note that category in item_details should be called loan period

Link to my view http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/8200/viewsm.png

Comment: Please tell us the intention of the query not just the faulty syntax. Are you trying to add a single row? One row for each row in the view?

Comment: @thebjorn The intention is to calculate lastreturndate of an item which is taking the value from CHECKOUTDATE and LOAN and adding them together.

Comment: Still unclear as to what you need. Please edit your question to show example data and desired results.

Comment: Does the view only contain a single row? If not it still isn't clear and you need to answer my previous question. Also does the table `Loan` not have any sort of key that you need to associate with lastreturndates?

Comment: @MartinSmith I added links to to ERD and my view, hopefully its easier to understand what im asking. Thanks again for helping out

Comment: @Sebastian did you really intend to do a `CROSS JOIN` in your view?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO Loan(lastreturndate) VALUES (@lastreturndate) 
FROM dbo.returndateview
```

try

```
insert into Loan(lastreturndate)
select ___ from dbo.returndateview where ___ = @lastreturndate
```

(you'll need to fill in the *_* with columns from your view).

.. or perhaps it is as simple as:

```
DECLARE @lastreturndate DATETIME
SELECT @lastreturndate = dateadd(month,loanperiod,CheckOutDate) FROM dbo.returndateview
INSERT INTO Loan(lastreturndate) VALUES (@lastreturndate)
```

based on your last edit, I think this is what you want:

```
update loan set
    lastReturndate = dateadd(month, detail.loanperiod, CheckOutDate)
from loan
join item on loan.barcode = item.barcode
join item_detals detail on item.isbn = detail.isbn
```

if you need your view, I believe you need to change it to:

```
create view returnDateView as
select
   detail.loanperiod,
   loan.CheckOutDate,
   loan.LastReturndate
from loan
join item on loan.barcode = item.barcode
join item_detals detail on item.isbn = detail.isbn
```

Comment: This is an update what im trying to do is apperently called a computed column(lastreturndate) but it doesnt work when one column is in another table. I think i misled you with the insert into statement which is completely unnecessary. Maybe i need to create a udf and somehow connect that to lastreturndate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying do an `UPDATE`. Assuming your view and Loan table are related by `loanid`, you could try

```
Update L set L.lastreturndate = dateadd(month,v.loanperiod,v.CheckOutDate)
From Loat L join dbo.returndateview v
            on L.loanId = v.loanId --You should have this relation
```

Or, if you could redesign your view as

```
create view dbo.returndateview
as
  select Checkoutdate,loanperiod,
       dateadd(month,loanperiod,CheckOutDate) lastreturndate
  from YourTable
```

Comment: No they are not related.Do they have to be related to create a view?

Comment: If they are not related, your data won't be related.

Comment: @Sebastian they don't have to be related to create a view, however, it seems like your data is related through the item table. Check out cross join from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 for what happens when you do not specify a relation.

Comment: @Kaf I redesigned my view as you said and it works.

Comment: Glad being able to help !